# What is the correct placement for the King and Queen on the chessboard?

Tags: rules, learning, pieces

What are the correct placements for the King and Queen set up on the board? I've heard things like, "white on the right and queen on her own colour" and "kings must not be facing each other." I'm sure its just an exact mirror on both sides; am I correct in placing the white square on the right and Queen on her own colour?

Comment: Yes, that is how it works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Each player has a white square on their near right corner. The queen goes on the square of her own color; as a result, the kings and queens face each other.

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Facing the chessboard, the Queen should be on the fourth square of the first rank (row) and the colour of the Queen should be the same as the colour of that square. (If the colours are different, rotate -90 or +90 degrees the chessboard.)

The King of a given color is on the square immediateley next to the square of the Queen of the same color and that is not taken by a light piece.